# Function to number array elements outputs "undefined"

Tags: javascript, prototype

I want to number each item in an Array, like this:

```
["hello", "hi", "hey"].number()
 > ["1. hello", "2. hi", "3. hey"]
```

Here's my code:

```
Array.prototype.number = function () {
    var tempNum = this;
    for (i in this) {
        tempNum[i] = tempNum[(i + 1)] + ". " + tempNum[i]
    }
    return tempNum;
}
```

But this is the output:

```
["hello", "hi", "hey"].number()
 > ["undefined. hello", "undefined. hi", "undefined. hey"]
```

Why? How should I implement this and why is my code not working?

Comment: This site is for reviews of working code. "How do I do X" or "Why does Y not work" questions belong on SO, where I'm now migrating this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
for(var i=0, len = this.length; i<len; i++){
    tempNum[i] = (i + 1) + ". " + tempNum[i];
}
```

you're using `tempNum` when you shouldn't be in the right side of your equation. The reason you're getting "undefined" is because at some point in your current equation you're getting an index outside of the length of your array.

Comment: did you try this? i would be a string, so you get '0' + 1 (become 01), '1' + 1 (become 11), '2' + 1 (become 21). So this won't solve the problem. You need to type cast it first

Comment: no, you wouldn't. `i` is going to be a number and 1 is a number. it gets cast to a string when you concat to the period. that's why i wrapped it in parens :) working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/gh8EN/

Comment: yes, you're right. I was thinking of for( ... in ... ) when I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 5):

The ES5 way:

```
Array.prototype.number = function () {
    return this.map( function ( value, i ) {
        return ( i + 1 ) + '. ' + value;
    });
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XSYTK/1/

*You'll need to shim .map() for IE8.*

Answer (score 3):

Inside your for loop, you're doing:

```
tempNum[i] = tempNum[(i + 1)] + ". " + tempNum[i]
```

If you just want to add numbers before each value, why are you getting `tempNum[(i + 1)]`?

It should look like:

```
Array.prototype.number = function () {
    var tempNum = this;
    for (var i in this) {
        tempNum[i] = (parseInt(i,10) + 1) + ". " + tempNum[i];
    }
    return tempNum;
}
```

Note the `parseInt(i,10)+1`.  This adds one to the index (after converting it to an int), and then prepends that to the string.

Answer (score 2):

`tempNum[(i + 1)]` is not what you want to do, you want something like `(i + 1)`. This also don't work, because keys are always strings. To type cast them to a float you can use `(parseFloat(i) + 1)` or, what is nicer, `(~~(i) + 1)`. The total code become:

```
Array.prototype.number = function () {
  var tempNum = this;
  for (i in this) {
    tempNum[i] = (~~(i) + 1) + ". " + tempNum[i]
  }
  return tempNum;
};

console.log(["hello", "hi", "hey"].number());
  // > ["1. hello", "2. hi", "3. hey"]
```

Comment: +1 neat trick with the `~` operator, but `parseInt()` is much more clear

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to modify the array values itself when invoking the `number()` function, because if you invoke the function again on the same array the numbering gets doubled. Instead better make a new array and return it like this:

```
Array.prototype.number = function () {
    var ret=[];
    var len=this.length;

    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        ret.push((i+1)+'. '+this[i]);
    }
    return ret;

}

console.log(["hello", "hi", "hey"].number());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LcHsY/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current solution is that in each iteration, i holds the value of the element, instead of the index.

So, when you do things like

```
tempNum[(i + 1)]
```

you are trying to add "hello" and 1, and this gives an undefined result.

So, in order to get your code working you could change your code as follows:

```
Array.prototype.number = function () {
  var tempNum = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < tempNum.length; ++i) {
    tempNum[i] = (i + 1) + ". " + tempNum[i]
  }
  return tempNum;
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect.  `i` contains the **key** (**index**), when doing `for(i in x)`.